# Validate middleware for node

Tags: node.js, express

In my node application, I have the following express route.

```
router.post('/register', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res) => {
   const { error } = validateUser(req.body); 
   if (error) 
      return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

   const { token, user } = await userService.createNewUser(req.body);
   res.header('x-authorization-token', token).send(_.pick(user, ['_id', 'name', 'email']));
}));
```

Is it a good practice to handle validation results like this? Or should I put this in to a middlerware and use it? If so, how can I put this in to a middlerware and use it?

Comment: This pattern is good. You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to handle validation results like this?

The answer is that **It Depends.**

If it is a small project or there are only a few APIs or you need validation for only this route then probably you can get around with validation like this.

But, in bigger projects, you should definitely have a separate validation middleware.
I personally like to use [express-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation) along with [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) for validation.

Joi is great for creating flexible and powerful schemas to validate the incoming request. and express-validation takes care of the appropriate status and body.

If you want to see an example of this, checkout my [express-api-structure](https://github.com/anandundavia/express-api-structure).